# Proof of $|A^T|=|A|$

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

I'm having problems with the step highlighted in green. It looks plausible but I can't convince myself it's correct.

Comment: It is correct. Here's my attempt to elaborate. For a given $i$, let $j = \pi(i)$, so that $\sigma(j) = \sigma(\pi(i)) = i$ because $\sigma = \pi^{-1}$. It follows that $(\pi(i), i) = (j, \sigma(j))$. Since we define $j$ by $j = \pi(i)$ and $\pi$ is a bijection, each $a_{\pi(i), i}$ on the left-hand side of the equation matches with exactly one $a_{j,\sigma(j)}$ on the right-hand side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $\pi$ is a permutation of the numbers $1, ..., n$. At the moment you have the product of $a_{\pi(i),i}$ as $i$ runs through $1, ..., n$.

Since $\pi$ is a permutation, we know that $\pi(i)$ will take all of the values $1, ..., n$. If we let $\pi(i) = j$ then we get:
$$
\pi(i) = j\\
\sigma(\pi(i)) = \sigma(j)\\
i = \sigma(j)
$$.
So we have the product of $a_{j, \sigma(j)}$. where we know that the values of $j$ are the values of $\pi(i)$, which are all the numbers $1, ..., n$.